# Electric field inside an insulator's cavity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, gauss-law

I'm trying to find the electric field inside insulating sphere's cavity, and I don't know how. However, if there was an conductor I'd know that $E=0$ from Gauss's Law.

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on the field on the outside (boundary conditions) and the dielectric constant of the insulator. For a imaginary insulating sphere of vacuum in a vacuum, it should be obvious that the sphere does not affect the electric field at all. Inside a dielectric, the field will be weaker than on the outside.

For a [dielectric sphere in a uniform electric field](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/10/21/dielectric-sphere-in-uniform-electric-field/), the field inside is a fraction $3/(2+\epsilon_r)$ of the external field; here $\epsilon_r$ is the relative dielectric constant of the dielectric.

***Update (responding to the comment)*** By the way, Gauss's law is not a good way to explain the absence of electric fields inside a conducting sphere. The reason is that any fields that are present will lead to charges moving, until the field of the displaced charges excancel the field.

Gauss's law only tells you that the sum of incoming and outgoing flux must be proportional to the charge inside the sphere. It doesn't imply that there is no field.

Comment: So there will be Electric field inside the cavity. But, because of Q=0 inside the cavity, can't we claim that E=0 because of Gauss Law? Can I use this law to find it?